# Как реализовать проверку на админа беседы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я беру от сервера это (код) как мне реализовать проверку на админа? брать id и сравнивать его если 'is_admin': True то выполнять код дальше а если нет показывать ошибку? Собственно проблема в том что я не могу понять как это сделать. (да немного тупой что поделать)

```
member_id = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id=peer_id)["items"][0]["member_id"]
is_admin = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id=peer_id)["items"][0]["is_admin"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
member_id = ...
is_admin = ...

assert is_admin == True, "Не админ: is_admin = {}".format(is_admin) # вывод ошибки и прерывание кода

# код дальше
```